# MS Access Query Compare Fields

Tags: ms-access

Problem: I cannot figure-out how to do the comparing of AccountID ABC's Status of "T" vs "ND" while also doing AccountID 123's at the same time

I have a query that pulls all the AccountIDs with the Status

TABLE:

AccountID --  SiteID -- Status

- ABC -- 1 -- **T**
- ABC -- 2 -- ND
- ABC -- 3 -- **T**
- 123 -- 1 -- **T**
- 123 -- 3 -- ND

Then a crosstab query that gives me the total of each Status for the AccountID

- ABC -- T = 2
- ABC -- ND = 1
- 123 -- T = 1
- 123 -- ND = 1

I need to take it a step further and compare the Status for each AccountID if there is a "T" and a "ND" change the "ND" to "PND". 
Sites with "T" do not need to show.

End result:

- ABC -- PND
- 123 -- PND

Comment: Don't understand what the difficulty is. Why do you feel a comparison is needed? Will there always be at least one "T" record for each account? Then just update the records with ND. Why were they not PND to begin with? Do you really want to change the raw data or just prefix the P in a textbox calculation?

Comment: I am pulling out all accounts and sites that have new data in them, some accounts can have over 150 sites and not all sites have data. I need to be able to create a list that says this account has no data at all and then account has some - ND = no data at all, PND = partial data. Unfortunately I cannot make any modifications to the database just query against it

Comment: So if an account has any site with a "T" AND a site with "ND" status, show the account as PND but if account has only "T" records don't show the account at all?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am aiming for. Googled the crap out of it but I must not be using the correct terms

Comment: So can an account have an ND record and no T record?

Comment: Yes, I guess I could make multiple Queries and then combine in another file

Comment: I don't know that multiple queries are necessary. Still trying to understand the data. Is that Yes an answer to my question?

Comment: Yes to your question. A site can have 4 different Statuses - T, ND, IP, IL. The IP and IL are independent from the other 2.  I need to be able to separate out is an account's site has data = T, if some of the account's sites have data and others do not = PND, and if an account has no data at all = ND. So in the end I will have 3 list: ND, PND, and IPIL

Comment: Isn't there a way where I can make a query that checks to see if there is a ND and a T for the same account number and if so choose that account number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like:

`SELECT DISTINCT AccountID, "PND" AS AdjStatus FROM table WHERE Status = "T" AND AccountID IN (SELECT AccountID FROM table WHERE Status = "ND");`